QGIS 3.38.3-Grenoble Points to path drawing lines that are not part of the track
I am working on a project for measuring the effort from our GPS tracks. The tracks were imported from .gpx files only with track_points.
When I use the Points to path for some tracks the lines are not drawn correctly, I need the lines to be drawn only over the points.
How can I easily remove the unnecessary line from the tracks, so I can measure the length correctly? I have already tried with Edit Geometry - Delete part/ Trim/extend feature with no success. The only solution that I've found is to delete or separate the tracks, but this does not work every time, and it is very time consuming.




Is "Create closed paths" unticked? What variable in the table above tracks the order of points  (e.g. the first point, second, etc.), other than the time?

Yes "created closed paths" is unticked. Only in these fields there are available data: fid,track_fid,track_seg_,track_se_1,ele,time. In the other fields from attribute table the data is NULL: magvar,geoidheigh,name,cmt,desc,src,link1_href,link1_text,link1_type,link2_href,link2_text,link2_type,sym,type,fix,sat,hdop,vdop,pdop,ageofdgpsd,dgpsid
